# SIMD program with MPI on a Windows network

Tags: c, windows, mpi, distributed-computing, simd

I have a network of computers(approximately 20), which has **MS Windows**(7, 10, Server 2008, Server 2012) installed on them.

All the computers have different **hardware specs**(different number of CPU cores) and are used by **many users** but in the **same domain**.

I have a program which calculates a formula(lets say the square root of a number) of some thousands/millions numbers and saves them on a database.

I need to **distribute portions** of these millions of numbers to the available CPU cores on the network.

Something like this:

```
int p, rank;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
int dsize = 1000000;
int part = dsize / p;
int bpart = part + (dsize%p);
if(rank==0)
{
    for(int i=1;i<p;i++)
    {
        int start = bpart+(i-1)*part;
        int stop = start+part;
        //SEND PORTION
        for (int s=start; s<stop;s++)
        {
            MPI_Send(...);
        }
    }
    CalcFormula(PORTION_OF_RANK0);
}//if rank0
else
{
    //RECEIVE PORTION
    MPI_Recv(...);
    CalcFormula(PORTION_OF_RANKi);
}//else rank!=0
```

What **libraries**(MSMPI, Open MPI, MPICH) and what **software** do you suggest me to use for an ***easy implementation***?

Comment: What have you tried already? What research have you done yourself, and what partial conclusions have you drawn? What specifically about the research you've done so far has led you to seeking outside opinions on the "correct" approach to take?

Comment: @Clint I tried MPICH(3.2) on Linux with two hosts(virtual machines), MS-MPI(7.1) on Windows 10 with one host(with the second host i still have some issues with smpd manager).
I cannot use Linux because it's impossible to switch the end users from Windows to Linux, so i have to stick with Windows.
I'm new in parallel and distributed computing and still searching, if you have something in your mind from your experience to recommend me, it will save me days of research.